# Find the inverse of the matrix.

Tags: matrices

Ok so I need to find the inverse of matrix $A=\begin{pmatrix}
 1& 0 &0  &...  & 0&0\\ 
 2& 1 & 0 & ... &0&0 \\ 
 0& 2 & 1 & ... & 0&0\\ 
 ...& ... & ... & ... & ...&...\\ 
 0& 0 & 0 & ... & 1&0\\
0&0&0&...&2&1
\end{pmatrix}$. I tried to do it on my own and here is the solution. Can you check if it is right?

[image: 1st page]

[image: 2nd page]

[image: 3rd page]

Comment: You can verify your solution by multiplying it with the original matrix $A$ to see if you get identity matrix.

Comment: I think it is good. I multiplied them and I got indentity matrix.

Comment: If you got the identity matrix then its correct, be more confident in yourself!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution seems correct to me. The standard way of solving this problem is to write the extended matrix
$$[A|I]$$
and then use Gauss elimination to get a matrix which is in echelon form. Since your matrix is already in this form (if transposed) you can simply use forward-elimination to get to the form
$$[I|A^{-1}].$$
Since every row $j$ of the solution matrix is multiplied by 2 and then subtracted from the subsequent row $j+1$, the coefficients of the inverse are given by
$$a^{-1}_{ij}=\begin{cases} 
      0 & j>i\\
      (-2)^{i-j} & j\leq i
   \end{cases}.$$

Comment: Ok thanks for the answer.